# How to boot UEFI installed Ubuntu in BIOS?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bios, 19.04

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 to an external HDD,in UEFI using a laptop.

I then tried booting it through my desktop (BIOS only, Windows 10), but an error popped up, about missing normal.mod file, prompting `grub rescue>`.
I figured out the normal.mod is in some x86_64-efi inside /boot/grub/ basically UEFI installed. But BIOS is trying to find it in /boot/grub/i386-pc.

Can i go to boot/grub and make copy of the x86_64-efi folder and name it i386-pc? 
Is that possible or do I have to format the disk or install in BIOS?
Can anyone suggest a lossless conversion method for GPT to MBR? 
Thank You

Comment: And you don't need to convert to MBR. Unlike Windows, Ubuntu can be installed in a GPT In Legacy mode, it just needs an unformatted bios_grub partition at the beginning of the drive.

Comment: No guarantees on conversion, but this usually works. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html
 Note that Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt and BIOS mode from UEFI. And Ubuntu needs an ESP if UEFI boot or a bios_grub if BIOS on gpt drives. I used to always but both as first two partitions on every new or repartitioned/reformatted drive and only used gpt.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this steps:

1. Install VirtualBox (or any other virtual machine emulator) onto your laptop.
2. Create virtual machine without UEFI in your case.
3. Mount to it `ubuntu.iso` and your physical external HDD via USB as a single boot drive.
4. Install Ubuntu.
5. Stop virtual machine and replug your HDD to desktop.